# SQL report organizing columns/rows

Tags: sql, report

Good morning, question about creating a report using SQL.  Have spent some time trying to figure out how to do this.  So here is the code...

```
select 
c.searchname as 'Client Name',
w.Date as 'Date',
j.Name as 'Engagement Name',
j.JobID as 'Eng #',
sum(units) as 'Hours',
ca.Description as 'Description'
from tblWip w
join tblJob j on w.jobid=j.jobid
join tblclient c on j.clientid=c.clientid
join tblChargeAccs ca on w.chargeacid=ca.ChargeAcID
where j.PartnerID='19'
group by c.searchname, j.name, w.date, j.jobid, w.units, w.amount, ca.description
order by c.searchname, w.date asc
```

Which outputs this...

[image]

I want to format the output to be more like this...

[image]

Any suggestions as to how I can rearrange these columns and rows?  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you for reading!

Comment: First - you should't do a report solely in SQL. Use a frontend tool for that. Secondly, if you want to format it like the report, you must pivot on the date column, and sum on Hours. We need to know your Database system, and you should be aware that the query should be made dynamically, since you do not know which dates will be needed.

Comment: Perfect, that is what I was wanting to know.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns are ordered exactly as you specify in the Select clause of your SQL.
The rows are ordered as you specify in the Order By Clause.

So to change these, just change how you write those two clauses:

```
select c.searchname 'Client Name',
   j.Name 'Engagement Name',
   j.JobID 'Eng #',
   sum(units) hours,
from tblWip w
   join tblJob j on w.jobid=j.jobid
   join tblclient c on j.clientid=c.clientid
   join tblChargeAccs ca on w.chargeacid=ca.ChargeAcID
where j.PartnerID='19'
group by c.searchname, j.name, w.date, 
  j.jobid, w.units, w.amount, ca.description
order by c.searchname, w.date asc
```

Getting the columns to reflect the date and having a separate column for each date in the data is harder. This is called  [Pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)ing the data. Google this as it is a topic of its own. Most database products have a built in function (in SQL Server it is called [Pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)) that will do this for you, but you need to read the docs (one link provided) to know how to use it properly.

If you know ahead of time which dates you need columns for, you could write it without dynamic Pivoting. Using your example data:

```
select c.searchname 'Client Name',
   j.Name 'Engagement Name',
   j.JobID 'Eng #',
   sum(case when w.Date = '25Jun2017' then units end) '25Jun2017hours',
   sum(case when w.Date = '26Jun2017' then units end) '26Jun2017hours',
   sum(case when w.Date = '27Jun2017' then units end) '27Jun2017hours'
from tblWip w
   join tblJob j on w.jobid=j.jobid
   join tblclient c on j.clientid=c.clientid
   join tblChargeAccs ca on w.chargeacid=ca.ChargeAcID
where j.PartnerID='19'
group by c.searchname, j.name, w.date, 
  j.jobid, w.units, w.amount, ca.description
order by c.searchname, w.date asc
```

Comment: Wonderful, this is the road map I was interested in.  Specifically the pivoting.  Thank you for explaining this!